# Compute the second derivative of the given distribution

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory

Consider on $\mathbb{R}^2$ the distribution defined by the locally integrable function $$ E(x,t) = \begin{cases} 
      1/2 & t - |x| > 0 \\
      0 & t - |x| < 0
   .\end{cases}
$$

Compute the distributional derivative $\frac{\partial^2 E}{\partial t^2} - \frac{\partial^2 E}{\partial x^2}.$

I'm not sure how to even start this problem, since to me, $E$ looks like a constant valued function whose derivative should be $0$ everywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Denote by $T$ the distribution defined by $E$. Moreover, let $U$ be the domain on which $E\neq 0$. Then for $\phi\in C_0^\infty(\mathbb R^2)$ we have
$$
T\phi = \int E(x,y)\phi(x,y)\,d(x,y) = \frac 12\int_U\phi(x,y)\,d(x,y).
$$
Now, by definition,
\begin{align*}
T_{yy}\phi
&= T\phi_{yy} = \frac 12\int_U\phi_{yy}(x,y)\,d(x,y) = \frac 12\int_{\mathbb R}\int_{|x|}^\infty\phi_{yy}(x,y)\,dy\,dx\\
&= -\frac 12\int_{\mathbb R}\phi_{y}(x,|x|)\,dx = -\frac 12\int_0^\infty\big[\phi_y(-x,x)+\phi_y(x,x)\big]\,dx.
\end{align*}
Similarly,
\begin{align*}
T_{xx}\phi
&= T\phi_{xx} = \frac 12\int_U\phi_{xx}(x,y)\,d(x,y) = \frac 12\int_0^\infty\int_{-y}^y\phi_{xx}(x,y)\,dx\,dy\\
&= \frac 12\int_0^\infty\big[\phi_{x}(y,y)-\phi_x(-y,y)\big]\,dx.
\end{align*}
Hence,
$$
T_{yy}\phi-T_{xx}\phi = -\frac 12\int_0^\infty\big[\phi_y(-t,t)+\phi_y(t,t) + \phi_{x}(t,t)-\phi_x(-t,t)\big]\,dt.
$$
Now, let $f(t) := (t,t)$. Then
$$
(\phi\circ f)'(t) = \phi'(f(t))f'(t) = (\phi_x(t,t),\phi_y(t,t))\binom 11 = \phi_x(t,t) + \phi_y(t,t).
$$
Similarly, if we set $g(t) = (-t,t)$, then $(\phi\circ g)'(t) = -\phi_x(-t,t) + \phi_y(-t,t)$. That is,
$$
T_{yy}\phi-T_{xx}\phi = -\frac 12\int_0^\infty\big[(\phi\circ f)'(t) + (\phi\circ g)'(t)\big]\,dt = \frac 12\big[\phi(f(0)) + \phi(g(0))\big] = \phi(0,0).
$$
Therefore, $T_{yy}-T_{xx} = \delta$.

Answer (score 2):

$E(x,t)$ can be rewritten as $\frac{1}{2}H(t-|x|)$. Would you know how to proceed now?

Comment: I know how to proceed from there, but how can the Heaviside function take two variables in its argument?

Comment: @kkc It's still taking a single real number $t-|x|$ as its argument.

Comment: @angryavian In that case, I have $E(u) = \frac{1}{2} H(u)$, but then can I simply take the partial derivatives? I'm not super comfortable with distributional calculus so I'm not sure if that's acceptable

Comment: @kkc This is not a distributional calculus issue anymore, it's a chain rule issue.

Comment: I obtain $\delta_{(0,0)}$.

Comment: @amsmath that's good news, because this is the fundamental solution for the 1-D wave equation! This highlights a very odd property of waves in 1-D, namely that they travel at all speeds less than or equal to their maximum, and that anything that propagates under this model never decays. If I shouted at you, you would never stop hearing echoes of the same volume - they would add and get louder over time.

Comment: @NinadMunshi Thanks for your text, but I don't seem to understand. Isn't the 1-D wave equation $u_{tt}-u_{xx} = 0$? Here, we get $\delta$ for a specific $u$.

Comment: @amsmath Yes that's what a fundamental solution means. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_solution)

Comment: @NinadMunshi I see. I must admit that I don't have a good understanding of physics stuff. If you wouldn't mind, I would be happy if you said a little more about how you get to, for example, the echo thing from the fact that $E_{tt}-E_{xx} = \delta$. What does this identity mean physically?

Comment: We can think of that delta as a sharp spike , i.e. we poke a system at exactly one location and one time (exactly singleton support) and see how it reacts. So in other words, this system responds to the initial poke (like a yell) with the fundamental solution. $Supp(E)$ tells us where that initial spike ends up going. Imagine an observer at the location $x$. Before $t=|x|$, the observer hears nothing. Starting at $t=|x|$, the observer suddenly hears a noise, but continues receiving that same noise forever (imagine characteristics of different speeds reaching the observer).

Comment: @NinadMunshi Ahhh, thank you so much. But, yeah, the volume is always $1/2$ (from the point on when I hear it). What did you mean before saying that they would add and get louder?

Comment: @amsmath That is if the speaker only yells a single shout at exactly one time. If there are more sounds produced, perhaps even something like a continuous tone, then the sounds from each consecutive time will keep building on the previous ones.

Comment: @NinadMunshi Ohhh, I see. So, if we start not only with one $\delta$ at place zero, but at $n$ places, the waves will hit me $n$ times and will amplify each time. I guess I learned something! Thank you so much!

Comment: @amsmath That is exactly correct and you are very welcome! In general if I have the fundamental solution $K$ to a linear pde $L$, then a solution to the inhomogeneous equation $Lu = f$ is given by $ u = K\star f$